# Problem Initializing terraform with s3 backend - CredentialRequiresARNError

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm having problems initializing terraform s3 backend in following setup. This works well with terraform version 0.11.15 but fails with 0.15.5 and 1.0.7.

There are 2 files:

**terraform.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  bucket = "test-bucket"
  acl    = "private"
}
```

**test-env.tfvars**

```
encrypt = true
dynamodb_table = "terraform-test-backend"
bucket = "terraform-test-backend"
key = "terraform/deployment/test-release.tfstate"
region = "eu-west-1"
```

When I run `terraform init -backend-config=test-env.tfvars` using terraform 0.11.15 it works and I can peform `terraform apply`. Here is the output:

```
Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically                                                                                                                                                                        
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Initializing provider plugins...                                                                                                                                                                                                              
- Checking for available provider plugins on https://releases.hashicorp.com...                                                                                                                                                                
- Downloading plugin for provider "aws" (2.70.0)...                                                                                                                                                                                           
* provider.aws: version = "~> 2.70"
```

But when I try to use versions 0.15.5 and 1.0.7 I get following error:

```
Error: error configuring S3 Backend: Error creating AWS session: CredentialRequiresARNError: credential type source_profile requires role_arn, profile default
```

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few changes were introduced with respect to the s3 backend and the way terraform checks for credentials in version >0.13.
Take a look at the the [following GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25134) or even more specifically  [this one](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/20062). In addition its outlined in the [Changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/v0.13/CHANGELOG.md)

I believe that the issue you are facing is related to the way your aws profile is set up (check your `~/.aws/config`).

Comment: Thank you :-) You're right a had a misconfigured config file.